# jquery (mobile): use flip switch to change theme of collapsible cotent

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a bunch of collapsible sets, within each is a flip switch which I use to post data. 
the result (which works) is

```
-itemA YES
-itemB NO
-itemC YES
...
-itemZ NO
```

I would like to have a visual clue that a set is selected (the switch is hidden within the set, so when closed, I have no clue if it was selected)

I found that I could use a theme to change the look, but HOW do I change the theme of the collapsible set that is parent of the switch only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the theme-specific classes of the collapsible widget to "highlight" it, here is an example:

```
//setup the classes and theme letters to use for on/off states
var classes = {
        on  : 'ui-btn-up-e ui-body-e',
        off : 'ui-btn-up-c ui-body-c'
    },
    themes  = {
        on  : 'e',
        off : 'c'
    };

//delegate the event handler binding for all toggle switches
$(document).on('change', '.ui-slider-switch', function () {

    //if the switch is "off"
    if ($(this).val() == 'off') {

        //find the parent collapsible widget of this switch, change its theme,
        //find the descendant header link and change it's theme attribute as well as class,
        //then go back to the collapsible selection and find the content wrapper
        //and change it's class to the "off" state class
        $(this).closest('.ui-collapsible').attr('data-theme', themes.off).find('a').attr('data-theme', themes.off).removeClass(classes.on).addClass(classes.off)
               .end().find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass(classes.on).addClass(classes.off);
    } else {

        //this does the same but backwards to make the "on" or active state
        $(this).closest('.ui-collapsible').attr('data-theme', themes.on).find('a').attr('data-theme', themes.on).removeClass(classes.off).addClass(classes.on)
               .end().find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass(classes.off).addClass(classes.on);
    }
});​
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtJyL/

Some documentation:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/switch/events.html

Note that the `classes` object I created stores two classes for `on` and two for `off`, both of these classes will be added/removed from an element when using the `classes` object. I didn't see any conflict with doing this in my JSFiddle but just be aware that this is a shortcut that isn't necessary.